# JSONP request with jQuery that doesn't append a "callback" parameter?

Tags: google-chrome, jquery, jsonp, http-get, script-tag

I have a local version of a JSONP response saved as a file so I can test my single-page web app from the local filesystem when I don't have an Internet connection.

It works fine when I load it directly from a `<script>` tag, but not when I try to load it with jQuery `$.ajax()` function. (Yes I have loaded jQuery successfully also from the local filesystem.)

I think it could be that jQuery *always* adds a `callback` parameter to the URL, and this doesn't make sense when the JSONP is coming from a statically named file rather than from the Internet.

I've tried passing `jsonpCallback` set to `null` or to the empty string `''`, but it makes no difference.

There are other oddities:

- It works fine from jQuery when I pass the full path as the URL but fails when I use a relative URL, even though both work equally well when directly using a `<script>` tag.
- When it fails, Google Chrome's developer tools network tab tells me the method was `OPTIONS` instead of `GET`! Using an absolute URL or the `<script>` tag method with either relative or absolute URL tells me the method is `GET` as expected.

Is this a known correct behaviour? A known incorrect behaviour?

Is something odd with jQuery or with Google Chrome? (I'm running in Windows 7 32 bit, Chrome version 21.)

Comment: @Esailija: No I'd heard of it but never used it before so forgot it existed. I'll do some experiments and update my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Esailija: Hmm this issue on the jQuery bug tracker that's closed "wontfix" makes it seem that `getScript()` is not worth pursuing: [GETSCRIPT() DOESN'T WORK FOR FILE: IN CHROME](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6703)

Comment: Ah, I assumed they would just create a script element instead of fetching it with xhr.

Comment: @Esailija: Me too, but they don't even provide options. It seems I'm working in a very undefined area - as I always seem to be (-:

Comment: You could always `$("<script>", {src: "..."}).appendTo("body").remove()`

Comment: @Esailija: Yes that's what I may end up doing after I fully understand the problem domain. But as jQuery will use script injection for JSONP anyway I'm still a bit baffled as to the exact reason(s) it's not working with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>While this might not solve all of my problems, it answers the specific problem posed in the question title:</s>

This seems to be what I was missing:

**JSONP request with jQuery that doesn't append a “callback” parameter?**

`jQuery.ajax()` takes a `settings` object parameter. One of these settings is called `jsonp`. [From the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **As of jQuery 1.5**, setting the `jsonp` option to `false` prevents jQuery from adding the "?callback" string to the URL or attempting to use "=?" for transformation. In this case, you should also explicitly set the `jsonpCallback` setting. For example, `{ jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }`

My code is now working with the current versions of Chrome (21), Firefox (13), Internet Explorer (9), Opera (12), and Safari (5) under Windows 7 (32 bit).